# Click() operation in selenium web driver is not helping me in redirecting to another page

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hi guys i need your help regarding the follwoing issue.

```
WebElement wb=driver.findElement(By.name("NavHeader1$tabs$ctl00$btnNavHeaderTab"));
        Actions act=new Actions(driver);
        act.moveToElement(wb).perform();
        driver.findElement(By.name("NavHeader1$tabs$ctl00$btnNavHeaderTab")).submit();
```

So to start from i am automating a site. I enter the site using the credentials and then i see a couple of tabs one of which i want to click and move forward but its not happening as the browser(Chrome) is just refreshing the same page and NOT REDIRECTING me to the page i desire
the backend code of the tab
for which i want the `click()` to work is

```
<input type="submit" 
   name="NavHeader1$tabs$ctl00$btnNavHeaderTab" value="File Tracking" 
   onclick="window.location.href='FileReceiptAssign.aspx';return false;" 
   id="NavHeader1_tabs_ctl00_btnNavHeaderTab" style="color:#003366;width:100px;">
```

Comment: You can use click method directly instead of Actions class. In your code change submit() to click(). Should work. Happy coding.

Comment: Well that is what i tried first and its not working so hence i used submit(). But that is also not helping me.

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
driver.findElement(By.id("NavHeader1_tabs_ctl00_btnNavHeaderTab")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

or:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("NavHeader1_tabs_ctl00_btnNavHeaderTab")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
```

another way (using jsExecutor):

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("var x = $('#NavHeader1_tabs_ctl00_btnNavHeaderTab');");
        stringBuilder.append("x.click();");
        js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
```

Comment: first two i tried and tested but it aint working. so will look at the third option and see. i feel that the onclick().window.href attribute does that stop the page from getting redirected as it returns false?

Comment: the third option that u provided is not throwing an error saying that $ is not defined.

Comment: also i can see that web driver has clicked on the tab but it aint changing the page. The site is also secure. if i open the site in internet explorer then the site does not show an address bar at all